# SDR - Read Only Repository vs CrudRepository

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

I am noticing rather peculiar behavior with ReadOnly repository and wondering if anyone else saw similar issue.

I've created the Read Only Repository interface as mentioned in the SDR docs. As you can see, the body of the class is just a copy paste of the in-built CrudRepository with only the GET methods retained.

**MyReadOnlyRespository.java**

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MyReadOnlyRespository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID>{

    Optional<T> findById(ID id);
    boolean existsById(ID id);
    Iterable<T> findAll();
    Iterable<T> findAllById(Iterable<ID> ids);
    long count();
}
```

And here is the UserRepostiory that extends the custom read-only repo.

**UserRepository.java**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path="users", collectionResourceRel="users")
public interface UserRepository extends MyReadOnlyRespository<User, Integer> {

}
```

With this configuration, when I access http://localhost:8080/services/users, I can see the following response, which is expected.

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "users": [
            {
                ....
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/services/users/1"
                    },
                    "user": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/services/users/1"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/services/users"
        },
        "profile": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/services/profile/users"
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to access the specific user by using the URL, I get method not supported error. http://localhost:8080/services/users/1.

But if I extend my UserRepository from the in-built CrudRepository instead of the custom MyReadOnlyRepository, the above URL for specific user gives the expected response. So what gives? Why is the custom repository failing?